# Is it legal to have a female only staff?

Tags: gender

A [report](https://thehustle.co/WeWork-invests-32-million-women-only-coworking-space?utm_source=daily&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=11%2F22%20-%20Net%20neutrality&utm_content=WeWork-invests-32-million-women-only-coworking-space) shows that WeWork is funding a female-only work environment for $32m. 
 
Doesn't this go against the Civil Rights Act of 1964 where a hiring manager can not discriminate in sex when hiring?

Comment: @Liam besides, if you read the title of the report you mention, they say that these women-only spaces are **Coworking spaces**... which is *really* different from a traditional company. Coworking spaces are usually open spaces where individuals can go network and share their knowledge with others, and "collectively" help each individual on the aspects they lack. It is common for startups or people wanting to begin their startups, as in coworker spaces you can find people that complement your skills. So, basically coworker spaces are no individual company per se.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Liam.  I've reopened the question and cleaned up a bunch of now-obsolete comments.

Comment: I initially thought the actual question was "is hiring females only against the Civil Rights Act?" with the article being just an example (albeit a rather poor one) to illustrate the point. Turns out I was wrong, this question is about that specific WeWork or whoever mentioned in that specific article, which is off-topic here. Moreover, if they are just renting out spaces to women, **where does a hiring manager come into the picture and what does it have to do with the Civil Rights Act?** Could you please [edit] to clarify what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Oh, I thought the question was general, like the title, but if it's asking for a legal judgement on that particular case, I agree it's off-topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WeWork's plan is to create a female only **coworking space**. The usual business arrangement with coworking spaces is that they are rented to self-employed people as a work environment. Those self employed people then use that space to pursue any business activity they want, unrelated to the company which owns the space.

So WeWork does not intend to hire only female employees. They intend to only serve female customers. That means laws which address discrimination during hiring decisions do not apply. There might be local laws which address customer discrimination based on sex, but that's not a workplace-related legal question.